# Html Canvas random start position to move afterwards

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, random

I am currently learning JavaScript.

I want the random start position of the cube to go up and down. This will cause the cubes to jump up and down on the Y axis.

I want the cubes to move up and down

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1TsP.png)

maybe like that:

```
Y = Y + speed;
if(Y <= 0) {
    speed = -speed;
}
if(Y >= canvas.width) {
    speed = -speed;
}
```

So that's my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
draw();
}
function draw(){
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height, "#cc33ff");
    for (var i=0; i <= 50; i++) {
        var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
        X = randX;
        var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
        Y = randY;
        speed = 10;
        var colorArray = ['#2185C5', '#7ECEFD', '#FFF6E5', '#FF6666'];    
        var randColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)];    
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.rect(X, Y, 20, 20);   
        canvasContext.fillStyle = randColor;
        canvasContext.fill();
        canvasContext.strokeStyle = "black";
        canvasContext.stroke();
        canvasContext.closePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: I want the cubes to move up and down

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is have an **initialisation routine** to determine the starting random position and then another to handle the **up/down movement**. What you have now is merely handling initialisation but not handling the next animation frame etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would need to save your squares in an array. You will also need a function to update the squares position. In my answer I'm using a function that updates all the squares and an other one that draws all the squares. A better solution would be to use the a function that draws or updates a single square, and to call that function for each square.

```js
var cw,ch,w = 20;
var squares = []

canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
// set the canvas width and height
cw = canvas.width = 800;
ch = canvas.height = 600;
canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

for (var i=0; i <= 50; i++) {
  // make a new square object
  var sq = {}
        var randX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (cw - w));
        sq.X = randX;
        var randY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (ch - w));
        sq.Y = randY;
        sq.speed = 1;
        var colorArray = ['#2185C5', '#7ECEFD', '#FFF6E5', '#FF6666'];    
        var randColor = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)]; 
        sq.color = randColor;
        // push the new square object into the squares array
        squares.push(sq);

    }

function Draw() {
// to animate the squares you will need to use the requestAnimationFrame method
window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);
canvasContext.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

draw();
update();
}

Draw();

function draw(){
    canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
    canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    for (var i=0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        var sq = squares[i];
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.rect(sq.X, sq.Y, w, w);   
        canvasContext.fillStyle =sq.color;
        canvasContext.fill();
        canvasContext.strokeStyle = "black";
        canvasContext.stroke();
        canvasContext.closePath();
    }
}

function update(){
// a function to update the squares position with every frame.
  for (var i=0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        var sq = squares[i];
        if(sq.Y >= ch - w || sq.Y <= 0){sq.speed *= -1;}
        sq.Y += sq.speed;
}
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Update all draw all is actually netter than update single draw single, easier for browser to optimize, but you'll want to make it smarter by conposing the less pathes as possible (i.e when consecutive rects share the same color, don't call beginPath, nor fill nor stroke). Also, what is closePath doing here?